# Is there a way to disable clicks on Views behind the ShowcaseView (inside the TargetView)?

Tags: java, android, showcaseview

Is there a way to disable clicks on views behind the ShowcaseView (inside the TargetView)? I have a very short tutorial and don't want users to be able to click through to elements behind the ShowcaseView because this interrupts its flow. Is there any way to disable clicking inside the TargetViews supplied to the ShowcaseView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view temporarily under the ShowcaseView but above anything you don't want clicked. Then call `view.setClickable(false)` this should prevent clicks from affecting that view or anything under it.

When you are done your showcase, just delete the extra view from the hierarchy.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable(boolean)

Comment: Have you managed to figure out how to create said blank View at a point just under the ShowcaseView?